# Does Sony DT 18-135mm SAM lens has Full-time Manual focus feature

Tags: lens, lens-design, sony, sony-alpha

I checked it in Len user-manual but Sony didn't mention about Full-time manual feature. I also checked it on Sony website but I didn't find any resources too.

Does anyone know the Len has Full-time Manual feature?

I found this in this forum - http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/50283922

> The 18-135 lens is unique among the SAM lenses, in that it is the only
>   one that allows full-time manual focus (like you get with the SSM
>   lenses).

I also found this

> Micromotor-type AF motor with full-time manual focusing

in this link: http://gearshop.dpreview.com/Sony-18-135mm-3-5-5-6-SAM-Lens/dp/B00836H3Z8

Thank you!

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide an actual source for that quote, rather than just "a forum"?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: I just added the post link. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research seems to indicate that it *does* have the "Full Time Manual Focus" feature.

From CameraDecision.com :

[image]

From an Amazon review:

[image]

And one more:

[image]

It seems to me that there is very little documentation on Sony lenses, which is a pity. :(